# BufferedImage causes a program freeze on MacOs but not on Windows

Tags: java, macos, lwjgl, bufferedimage

I'm using a [piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819030/how-to-make-a-simple-screenshot-method-using-lwjgl) to grab a *screenshot* of my application screen for a group project. On my Macbook Pro the code freezes the screen whereas on my teammates's PC's (all Windows) it runs just fine and exports a .png file in their root dir.

### The code

```
public void screenShot(){
    //Creating an rbg array of total pixels
    int[] pixels = new int[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
    int bindex;
    // allocate space for RBG pixels
    ByteBuffer fb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(WIDTH * HEIGHT * 3);

    // grab a copy of the current frame contents as RGB
    glReadPixels(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, fb);

    // convert RGB data in ByteBuffer to integer array
    for (int i=0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        bindex = i * 3;
        pixels[i] =
                ((fb.get(bindex) << 16))  +
                        ((fb.get(bindex+1) << 8))  +
                        ((fb.get(bindex+2) << 0));
    }
    //Allocate colored pixel to buffered Image
    BufferedImage imageIn = null;
    try{
        //THIS LINE 
        imageIn = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        //THIS LINE ^^^^^ 
        imageIn.setRGB(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, pixels, 0 , WIDTH);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

---

### The problem

When debugging I can see that when stepping in at this line

```
imageIn = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

the debugger doesn't go to the BufferedImage constructor but to GLFWKeyCallbackI.callback() and after that to GLFWCursorEnterCallbackI.callback(). After this it stops altogether.

### What I tried

In my main class above all the rest of the code making a buffered Image as such:

```
BufferedImage imageIn = new BufferedImage(100,100,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

It also freezes the simulation but it does seems to actually execute the line.

---

I'm not sure what else I could try, I saw a few other posts ranging between 2005 and today asking similar Mac questions without an answer.

Comment: Any stack trace?

Comment: Nope , really annoying. It just stops.

Comment: I have no solution for you, but maybe take a look at both the native mac logs and some memory stats in the activity monitor to see if there's anything useful in there - might be a system issue with awt.

Comment: Most likely, there's some threading issue between OpenGL and Java AWT (and perhaps the MacOS process "main" thread).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I delved a bit deeper and discovered the issue. As mentioned in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809275/creating-a-bufferedimage-causes-glfw-in-the-lwjgl-to-lock-up-java) if I provide this VM option "-Djava.awt.headless=true" it seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Holy smoke, I've spent weeks trying to fight the same thing Thanks so much for posting it!